# How to force Google cloud vision to use a specific charset?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have a large set of difficult words to recognize through ᴏᴄʀ.

The image are all of lowercase latin alphabet without diatrics, but despite using languagehints, I end up with results like `学会学论發及` in a lot of cases.

So how to force Google cloud vision to use a specific set of letters and not just hint ?

Comment: I don’t mind about the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to “force” vision API to use a specific set of characters. Even if that was the case, the ML model could still not be able to predict the correct result.

It may be worth opening a public issue through [this form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1010433), detailing your use case and the difficulties you are encountering. Perhaps a product enhancement can come from that.